# How to get Laravel resource API in react.js

Tags: reactjs, api

I just learn react js recently. Now, I face a problem when I want to the the API result in react .js.

this is my laravel resource API

```
{
   "data": {
     "project_id": 2,
     "project_name": "Starbucks (Demo) Residences",
     "created_by": "Kwang",
     "developer": {
     "developer_name": "Marina (Demo) Property Sdn. Bhd.",
     "created_by": "Kwang",
     "total": 45
   },
 "total_phase": 4,
 "phase_name": []

}
```

Now , I want to request this API in react js using Axios. I set the state as single_project. Then,I get the API url to obtain the data. The data can be shown in my console.log.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class ProjectInfo extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {single_project:[]}
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('http://sale.test/api/project/2')
    .then(res => {
      let single_project = res.data;
      this.setState({single_project});
      console.log(single_project); //I get the data here
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
     <div className="developer-panel">
       {this.state.single_project.project_name} //I cannot get this
     </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ProjectInfo;
```

I can console the data from API succesfully. However , I cannot render out the result with `{this.state.single_project.project_name}`

Anyone please help me !!

Appreaciate any suggestion or solution.

Comment: Check out https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-react-app-with-laravel-restful-backend-part-1-laravel-5-api--cms-29442

Comment: Thanks, but your articles is not related to my problem man.

Comment: When you console.log data in componentDidMount what is the type of data.Is it object or stringified??

Comment: @pritesh thanks for your reply man, it return as object

Comment: @pritesh , I not sure is it the 'data' in front of my API, since i build this API with using laravel resource.

Comment: when you console.log the response is it the same as the data you pasted above?

Comment: It does not matter if you using laravel resource as long as you are returning json data in your response.So that should not be the problem

Comment: @pritesh, yupp it is samee

Comment: @pritesh, but there is an array which is 'phase name 'in the return json data